# create many columns and set value based on previous columns by lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a table with description of symptoms like below:

```
DT <- data.table(no = c(1, 2, 3),
symptom = c("headache and numbness", "tachycardia, sometimes headahce", "breath difficulty with limb numbness"))
```

the keywords I'm focusing on look like this

```
key.word <- list(
  head = c("head", "headache"),
  chest = c("breath", "tachycardia", "palpitaion")
```

I want to add two columns that describe whether the keyword is mentioned in the variable *symptom*, the desirable result looks like this

```
    result <- data.table(no = c(1, 2, 3),
                 symptom = c("headache and numbness", "tachycardia, sometimes headahce", "breath difficulty with limb numbness"),
                 head = c(T, T, F),
                 chest = c(F, T, T))
```

I can do this job by

```
DT[symptom %like% paste0(head, collapse = "|"), head := T]
DT[symptom %like% paste0(chest, collapse = "|"), chest := T]
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with lapply and datatable? (which seemed to be more elegant). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option

```r
DT[ , lapply(
    key.word, function(x) any(sapply(x, function(w) grepl(w, symptom)))), 
    by = list(no, symptom)]
#   no                              symptom  head chest
#1:  1                headache and numbness  TRUE FALSE
#2:  2      tachycardia, sometimes headahce  TRUE  TRUE
#3:  3 breath difficulty with limb numbness FALSE  TRUE
```

The internal `sapply` loop is necessary as `pattern` in `grepl` is not vectorised.

---

### Update

In response to your comment, you can do

```r
DT[ , (paste0("symptom_", names(key.word))) := lapply(
    key.word, function(x) any(sapply(x, function(w) grepl(w, symptom)))), 
    by = list(no, symptom)]
#   no                              symptom symptom_head symptom_chest
#1:  1                headache and numbness         TRUE         FALSE
#2:  2      tachycardia, sometimes headahce         TRUE          TRUE
#3:  3 breath difficulty with limb numbness        FALSE          TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry for an additional question. Is there a way I can add prefix to each created column so that the new column name would look like *symptom_head*, *symptom_chest*?

Comment: You're very welcome @IanWang; please see my edit as a response to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking only for DT or lapply option, but using dplyr and stringr:

```
DT %>% mutate(head = str_detect(symptom, str_c(key.word[[1]], collapse = '|')),
               chest =str_detect(symptom, str_c(key.word[[2]], collapse = '|')))
   no                              symptom  head chest
1:  1                headache and numbness  TRUE FALSE
2:  2      tachycardia, sometimes headahce  TRUE  TRUE
3:  3 breath difficulty with limb numbness FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I'm looking for a data.table method with apply function, but still many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem. I prefixed the column names with sympton_ to take into account your comment [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657654/create-many-columns-and-set-value-based-on-previous-columns-by-lapply#comment130071454_73657739). Note that I used `lapply` to adapt your attempt to find a solution.

```
DT[, paste0("symptom_", names(key.word)) := 
     lapply(lapply(key.word, paste0, collapse="|"), grepl, symptom)]


      no                              symptom symptom_head symptom_chest
   <num>                               <char>       <lgcl>        <lgcl>
1:     1                headache and numbness         TRUE         FALSE
2:     2      tachycardia, sometimes headahce         TRUE          TRUE
3:     3 breath difficulty with limb numbness        FALSE          TRUE
```